# How to convert varchar '15:01:2008 02:07:23 PM' to datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the format of data available

```
'15:01:2008 02:07:23 PM'
```

and I want to convert into

```
'2008-01-15 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Look at `CONVERT`

Comment: Don't store strings instead of dates to begin with. Dates have no formats anyway, they're binary values.

Comment: What a perverse format. `SELECT STUFF(STUFF('15:01:2008 02:07:23 PM', 3, 1, '-'), 6, 1, '-')` will at least get you something that `CONVERT`/`TRY_PARSE` can eat (with appropriate style flags).

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server doesn't have very flexible date parsing capabilities.  You can piece this together by parsing the date and times separately.  Happily, if you do this as `datetime`, you can just add the results:

```
select (convert(datetime, replace(left(str, 10), ':', '/'), 103) + 
        convert(datetime, right(str, 12))
       ) as real_datetime
from (values ('15:01:2008 02:07:23 PM')) v(str)
```